# Database automatically changing/reverting

Tags: mysql

So something bizarre happened today and I was looking for a reason why.

I have a table of leads, that have a column for city.

I have 40,000 so far.  There were 1200 in Crofton, BC.

These were entered wrong., So I did an SQL Update as follows....

```
UPDATE leads SET city='Metchosin' WHERE city='Crofton' AND status='active'
```

Which worked, and affected all 1200 rows. (according to PHPmyadmins message)

However.....today, someone using the system said that there were still leads under Crofton, BC.

I was expecting maybe 2-3 that were missed by the UPDATE, either cuz the rows were locked at the time, or whatever.

But all 1200 leads had reverted back to Crofton!!!!!  Overnight...

How can this happen???  Thats very scary, cuz who knows what else data is just randomly being changed.

Any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: Triggers on your table?Cron job?

Comment: I have no triggers or cron jobs.....unless Appfog does something overnight that Im not aware of

Comment: if you made the changes from command line, what is the default value of "autocommit" setting? It could be possible that the autocommit is set to false and you didn't commit your update, terminated the session and so the changes were not permanent.

Comment: I made the changes from within PHPmyadmin.  And verified from within the app that the changes were made as well.  For 18 hours, the leads had the correct city attached to them, then this morning they were all back to the old city....and who knows what else changed.  Im wondering if Appfog had anything to do with it....maybe they had a snapshot of my table, and 'restored it' for some reason.  But thats worrisome, as that means any changes that happened during that time are also no recorded??